# Stretched ImageButton

Tags: android, size, imagebutton

I have created an Android `layout` by using few `ImageButtons`. My layout works fine on small screens (e.g. 3.6 inch to 4.2 inch), but when I use my application on 7 inch or 9 inch tablets the `layout` becomes ugly in both portrait and landscape mode. I didn't use any pixel dimensions for the `ImageButton`. How can I fix this?

On 4 inch screens:

[image: on 3.8"]

On 7 inch screens:

[image: on 7"]

This is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="35dp"
       android:background="#81BEF7"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/buttonlayout" android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:height="32dp" android:gravity="left|top" android:background="#000000"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" android:paddingBottom="2dp">
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgbtn1"
                                android:layout_width="32dp" android:layout_height="32dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/logo" />
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTest" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:text="Max-Apps" android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                android:textSize="15sp" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2" android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                        </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayoutTop"
                        android:layout_gravity="left" android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRowTop"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
                </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/select_names_tags_ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPageTwo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Featured" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Category"
        android:onClick="onClickCategory" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Top Download" 
        android:onClick="onClickList"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="About us" />
</LinearLayout>    
</HorizontalScrollView>

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"        
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="@drawable/winnie"
            android:onClick="onClickPageTwo" /> 0       

        <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_margin="2dip"                                 
                 android:background="@drawable/games"
                 android:onClick="onClickPageTwo" /> 
    </LinearLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/papago"
            android:onClick="onClickPageTwo" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"        
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="1.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01">        

        <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_margin="2dip"                                 
                 android:background="@drawable/winnie"
                 android:onClick="onClickPageTwo"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="@drawable/mickey"
            android:onClick="onClickPageTwo" />
    </LinearLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>           


<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"        
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="1.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:background="@drawable/fb"                         
            android:onClick="onClickPageTwo" />
    </LinearLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>            
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you used res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

Comment: i cant read, can u give more details with a proper format at the answer section? thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

(1) You can put the images of different sizes in different folders  i. e. hdpi, mdpi, ldpi for big screens, medium screens and low-size screens respectively. Device will automatically pick the image for itself according to its size.

(2) Create a new folder named "layout-land" in the "res" folder and create your xml file with the same name(as of your main xml file) in this folder. Just copy and paste the code of your main xml file into this file.
Now create a method (actually override) "onConfigurationChanged()" in your activity class and copy-paste the code of "onCreate()" method into it.

After doing the above 2 steps , you will see that no matter what the size or orientation of the device is , your app's layout will always be correct and as per wanted.